# Forcing AddThis Buttons to Create Custom Facebook Message

Tags: php, facebook, angularjs, slim, addthis

I've been trying everything to force a Facebook share with the AddThis toolbox to populate the user message when hitting the share button. Moreover, I'm hoping to include a global parameter that tracks points from within the Slim PHP framework and with Angular frontend. I was hoping I'd be able to make the force without changing anything in the MVC

From the Page.html partial template:

```
<a class="addthis_button_facebook" addthis:title="CUSTOM TITLE"  addthis:description="CUSTOM DESCRIPTION WITH {{points}}"></a>
```

Within the app.js angular file:

```
myApp.directive('fbLike', function () {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        template: '<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.winshuttle.com/sap-quiz/"     data-colorscheme="light" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-send="false"></div>'
    }
});
```

Comment: That would be against Facebook Platform Policy https://developers.facebook.com/policy 2.3: "Ensure that all content in the user message parameter is entered by the user. Don’t pre-fill. This includes posts, messages, comments, and captions."

Comment: What about just adding open graph tags just to update the title/description? Those aren't deprecated right? I've been trying a dozen different things to get those meta tags just to work.

Comment: Yes you can change the og-tags on your site

Comment: Yeah, I tried. For some reason it's not catching, when I use the Facebook debugger it keeps pulling up a "canonical" link instead. I tried adding the OG meta tags on pretty much every templated page header I could, yet it still ignores. Thanks though.